# Database-independent queries to the extreme in Java... or in general

Tags: persistence, platform-independent

Let's say I have an app that should ideally be able to use a relational database, object database, XML files, or whatever to persist its data. In the spirit of coding to interfaces instead of implementations, I have a generic DataStore interface that specifies a contract for all I/O involving the data store. This interface can be implemented by concrete classes such as RDBMSDataStore, OODBMSDataStore, XMLFileDataStore, and so on.

This works well as long as I keep the contents of the DataStore interface simple - i.e. `getThis()`, `getThose()`, `saveThat()`, `updateThis()`, etc. But as soon as I require more complicated queries, it breaks down. The XMLFileDataStore class obviously doesn't understand SQL, and the RDBMSDataStore class obviously doesn't understand XPath/XQuery. And OODBMSDataStore understands something entirely different depending on the OODBMS in use.

I could adopt a language-independent object query language, write all my queries in that and then have the concrete classes translate them into their native language, but that's a huge task, if I want to be complete.

Are there standards or best practices for handling this kind of situation in Java? Unfortunately it seems like 99% of the world interprets "database independence" to mean "relational database independence" and ignores the object databases, XML databases, document databases, etc. entirely.

Answer (score 0):

From the way I read the question, this sounds a lot like the semantic that [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) brings to the table for Java. It even has mode for dealing with XML as the content backing store (using Dom4J). The Hibernate API has a number of extension points that could allow the addition of an OODBMS model. Even if Hibernate turns out not to be the best solution for you (implementation-wise), I think it provides a good example of the types of patterns that can be used to solve the problems you proposed.